# Is there any possibility to access XML files in html

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I'm developing an android application using PhoneGap. Actually, I have images that are created with XML file so is there any possibility to access that XML files via an HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the xml file is in the device file system you can access with javascript.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File

If in a remote host, you can retrieve it´s content with a ajax request.
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Good Luck!